# Popup em PHP após retornar Sucesso

Tags: php, javascript, popup

Tenho um formulário de contato, simples e gostaria que ao a pessoa enviar a mensagem, caso dê sucesso, aparecesse uma popup dizendo que a mensagem foi enviada.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Para ajudar vou colocar parte do code `PHP` aqui:

```
 [..] 
 $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
 if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
 echo "concluido";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Se minha resposta te ajudou, pode marcar como aceita :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementar, meu caro Watson:

```
 [..] 
 $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
 if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
            ?>
            <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--
            alert("Sucesso!");
            window.location = '/index.php';
            //-->
            </script>
            <?

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Agradeço amigo, certinho o que eu precisava

Comment: Mas assim vai parecer site do governo brasileiro. Te aconselho a usar modal do bootstrap ou fancybox para ter o mínimo de elegância. Existem diversos exemplos prontos pela internet.

Comment: Particularmente não me cai bem essa história de misturar php e javascript, para isso que existe uma infinidade de seletores. Prefiro colocar uma id em alguma div e a partir dele executar o script